# Animation each UIView inside the StackView

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I need to animate a UIViews inside stackView like this.

[image]

This image is a gif  (click to show)

I create an UIView Extension like this

```
func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 1.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(_: Bool) -> Void in }) {
            self.alpha = 0.0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.isHidden = false
                self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: completion)
        }
```

And for each UIView inside the StackView assigned the animation like this

```
stackView.subviews.forEach { currentView in
    currentView.fadeIn()
}
```

but all views appear at the same time. I try to add a delay time but doesn't work correctly. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: What image? I don't see an image link.

Comment: @DuncanC Sorry when I edited the question I deleted the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
stackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated().forEach { (index,item) in
   item.fadeIn(delay:Double(index)*1.5)
}
```

with

```
 func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 1.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(_: Bool) -> Void in }) {
   self.alpha = 0.0
   UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
     self.isHidden = false
     self.alpha = 1.0
   }, completion: completion)
}
```

Comment: Sh_Khan, you beat me to it. (Voted). Don’t you need to cast index to a ‘Double’ in the call to ‘fadeIn’ to avoid an error though?